# ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken when ever I am trying to execute HQL

Tags: spring, hibernate

The following exception is occurring when I try to execute HQL in my code. I checked this in various sites and found that antlr.2.7.6.jar shd be in class path. I checked this in my project and found that this is there in my Maven dependencies. So there should not be any such issue. But still I am getting this issue. Can anyone help me in this regard. I am getting this error in line "empList = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Employee");" in the following function.

```
public List<EmployeeTO> getAllEmp() {
    List<Employee> empList =  new ArrayList<Employee>();
List<EmployeeTO> empListTO =  new ArrayList<EmployeeTO>();
empList = getHibernateTemplate().find("from Employee");
try {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(empListTO, empList);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return empListTO;
}
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
Root cause of ServletException.
     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [from com.myapp.domain.Employee]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [from com.myapp.domain.Employee]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [from com.myapp.domain.Employee]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.panic(HqlLexer.java:80)
    at antlr.CharScanner.setTokenObjectClass(CharScanner.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.setTokenObjectClass(HqlLexer.java:54)
    at antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:51)
    at antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Currently I am using weblogic 12c and Hibernate 3.6.9.

And in one of the site I found that we need to add `antlr.2.7.6.jar` file in weblogic `pre_compile` path variable.

1. Weblogic 12c:  For Weblogic versions which are Java EE 6 compliant, we need to add only antlr jar dependency.
2. Download and place the below files under `<WL_HOME>/common/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar`
3. Add the above files in classpath

**For Windows:**

Add the below line in */common/bin/commEnv.cmd*

```
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%/common/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
```

**For Linux:**

Add the below lines in */common/bin/commEnv.sh*

```
<WL_HOME>/PRE_CLASSPATH=$WL_HOME/common/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
```

Export `PRE_CLASSPATH`

I followed these steps on my window machine. For my case **wl_home** was set to `C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1v` here within *common/lib*.

I added this jar and added set `PRE_CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%/common/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar` code in  */common/bin/commEnv.cmd* and restarted weblogic. This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your exact hibernate needs, it may be possible to remove the antlr dependency entirely.  By adding this to your hibernate properties you may be able to run without issue:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

Comment: I faced this problem migrating from hibernate 2 to 3. This is the only solution that worked for me. Moreover I'm on production environment and cannot change the server configuration, cannot add libraries nor execute commands. Thanks @John

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue in weblogic 10.3, having antlr-2.7.7.jar in the application classpath and was able to resolve it by adding a prefer-application-packages of "antlr.*" in the file weblogic-application.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the weblogic.xml file to prefer-application-packages.  Check out [this forum post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/28101-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hql-ast-hqltoken) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
The package name 'rescuetrailer' is already been used by another package: {PackageConfig Name:rescuetrailer namespace: abstract:false parents:[{PackageConfig Name:webwork-default namespace: abstract:false parents:[]}]}
Could not execute action
org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [from pinacle.person.model.Person p where p.jobNo='meiql']
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.panic(HqlLexer.java:57)
    at antlr.CharScanner.setTokenObjectClass(CharScanner.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.setTokenObjectClass(HqlLexer.java:31)
    at antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:51)
    at antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.<init>(HqlLexer.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlParser.getInstance(HqlParser.java:44)
```

weblogic 10.3.6 
jdk 1.6
centos7.6

just do this

```
cat $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.sh | grep PRE_CLASSPATH

export PRE_CLASSPATH=/YOUDIR/antlr-2.7.6.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying the antlr.2.7.6.jar into Web Logic Lib directory and setting the PRE_CLASSPATH to this jar file worked for me. The weblogic server starts earlier than the custom application you are working on. So setting it's pre_classpath in the common environment will load the classes and you won't get that ClassNotFoundException exception. Note I am using Windows.

```
@the weblogic lib directory is loacated in <WL_HOME>\common\lib\

@Modify commEnv.cmd or commEnv.sh located in <WL_HOME>\common\bin\ as follows
@after WL_HOME (Web Logic Server Home Directory) has been set ...
@rem Set WebLogic Home
set WL_HOME=E:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3

@set the pre_classpath
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%\lib\antlr.jar
set CLASSPATH=%PRE_CLASSPATH%;%CLASSPATH%
```