# ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken

Tags: java

I have a web application that normally runs fine in weblogic 9.2 but facing following Issue while migrating weblogic 9.2 to 10.3.6.

```
Aug 27, 2014 7:35:07 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
SEVERE: Error in named query: getOutstandingDetailsByAgreementBetweenDatesFromRCMDate
org.hibernate.QueryException: ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlToken [SELECT model FROM com.crisil.ratings.sfb.batch.engine.model.SfbAgreementOutstandDetsVw model WHERE model.agreementId = :agreementId AND model.rcmDate BETWEEN TO_DATE (:rcmDate1, 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE (:rcmDate2, 'dd-mm-yyyy')]
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.panic(HqlLexer.java:57)
at antlr.CharScanner.setTokenObjectClass(CharScanner.java:340)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.setTokenObjectClass(HqlLexer.java:31)
at antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:51)
at antlr.CharScanner.<init>(CharScanner.java:60)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:56)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:53)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseLexer.<init>(HqlBaseLexer.java:50)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlLexer.<init>(HqlLexer.java:26)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlParser.getInstance(HqlParser.java:44)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:402)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:352)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:730)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:127)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:39)
at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:349)
at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:124)
at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:58)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:1827)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initClassLoader(WebAppServletContext.java:3029)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:448)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Aug 27, 2014 7:35:07 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
```

What's the best way to fix this?

I'm using Hibernate3, JPA 1.0, Struts 2.0 and WebLogic 10.3.6

I have tried uggested solutions but not working for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819450/classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-hql-ast-hqltoken-when-ever-i-am-trying-to

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Exception has anything to do with WebLogic Server migration. Whenever you are trying to get Hibernate session, it loads all mapping files and named queries.
You are getting error when Hibernate is trying to initialize its `SessionFactory` and your named query in your Mapping File (.hbm.xml) or annotated class file is syntactically wrong.

The named query ***getOutstandingDetailsByAgreementBetweenDatesFromRCMDate*** is incorrect. Just try fixing it or if nothing works, comment it out. Named Query errors such as ***Error in named query*** or ***DuplicateNamedQuery*** are quite common and wont let your Hibernate Session get initialized even if you are not using them.

Comment: Thank Kumar for your kind suggestion.